# Не работает Telegram бот, моментально закрывается

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Работаю с Python 2-3 дня и надо по искусству сделать проект, который через Telegram бота будет выводить различные сообщения. Вот сам код, ошибок не выдает, а просто моментально закрывается:

```py
import telebot
import os
from getch import pause

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши мне Начать')
path = r"C:\Users\Tareli\Desktop"
os.listdir(path)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
     if message.text == 'Начать':
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хочешь начать топ 5 знаменитых художников средневековья? ')
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что бы узнать про любого из них напиши: ')
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чимабуе , ')
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Жан Фуке , ')
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Джорджо Вазари , ')
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Лоренцо Монако , ')
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '5 ')
         if message.text == 'Чимабуе':
             bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' 1. Чимабуэ настоящее имя — Ченни ди Пепо, Итальянский живописец, один из главных мастеров итальянской живописи периода проторенессанса.Про него писал даже Данте в «Божественной комедии» вот этот отрывок: Кисть Чимабуэ славилась одна, А ныне Джотто чествуют без лести, И живопись того затемнена.Его самая известная работа это мозаика изображающая св. Иоанна Богослова')
             file1 = "1.jpg"
             doc = open('path' + '/' + file1, 'rb')
             caption1 = "Иоанн Богослов, Пиза. Сохранившимися счетами подтверждено авторство Чимабуэ ."
             bot.send_photo(chat_id, doc, caption1)
         elif message.text == 'Жан Фуке':
              bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '2. Жан Фуке — французский живописец, первый мастер французского Возрождения, портретист и миниатюрист, глава Турской школы. Жан Фуке родился в г. Тур в долине Луары,Самая его популярная картина это «Взятие Иерусалима»')
              file2 = "2.jpg"
              doc = open('path' + '/' + file2, 'rb')
              caption2 = "Жан Фуке. «Взятие Иерусалима»."
              bot.send_photo(chat_id, doc, caption2)
         elif message.text == 'Джорджо Вазари':
              bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Джорджо Вазари  — итальянский живописец, архитектор и писатель. Автор знаменитых «Жизнеописаний», основоположник современного искусствознания. Первым учителем Вазари, когда ему ещё не было двенадцати лет, стал французский художник Гильом де Марсилья, расписывавший витражи церкви в Ареццо. В 1524 году он жил во Флоренции, учился у Андреа дель Сарто, Микеланджело и Баччо Бандинелли. Молодому Вазари покровительствовали Алессандро Медичи и Ипполито Медичи, которые вскоре были вынуждены покинуть Флоренцию. Вазари вернулся в Ареццо, где получил несколько заказов и даже писал фрески.')
              file3 = "3.jpg"
              doc = open('path' + '/' + file3, 'rb')
              caption3 = "Самая популярная картина его картина это Вазари — «Погребение Иисуса» (1532 год, дом-музей Вазари в Ареццо)."
              bot.send_photo(chat_id, doc, caption2)
         elif message.text == 'Лоренцо Монако':
              bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Лоренцо Монако имя до пострига Пьеро ди Джованни — флорентийский художник.Точная дата рождения художника неизвестна. Исследователи сходятся на том, что он родился около 1370 года (разные авторы высказывают предположения от 1367 года до середины 1370х). Место рождения Лоренцо так же нельзя считать точно установленным фактом. В одном раннем документе утверждается, что он выходец из прихода церкви Сан Микеле Висдомини во Флоренции, в другом архивном документе от 29 января 1415 года он фигурирует как «don Lorenzo dipintore da Siene», то есть «дон Лоренцо живописец из Сиены», однако некоторые эксперты считают, что эта запись недостаточно чёткая и поэтому неправильно интерпретирована.')
              file4 = "4.jpg"
              doc = open('path' + '/' + file4, 'rb')
              caption4 = "Лоренцо Монако, Мадонна Смирение со святыми, 1385—1390, Галерея Академии, Флоренция. Ранний пример использования Лоренцо готической стилистики."
              bot.send_photo(chat_id, doc, caption4)
         elif message.text == '5':
              bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Лоренцо Монако имя до пострига Пьеро ди Джованни — флорентийский художник.Точная дата рождения художника неизвестна. Исследователи сходятся на том, что он родился около 1370 года (разные авторы высказывают предположения от 1367 года до середины 1370х). Место рождения Лоренцо так же нельзя считать точно установленным фактом. В одном раннем документе утверждается, что он выходец из прихода церкви Сан Микеле Висдомини во Флоренции, в другом архивном документе от 29 января 1415 года он фигурирует как «don Lorenzo dipintore da Siene», то есть «дон Лоренцо живописец из Сиены», однако некоторые эксперты считают, что эта запись недостаточно чёткая и поэтому неправильно интерпретирована.')
              file4 = "4.jpg"
              doc = open('path' + '/' + file4, 'rb')
              caption4 = "Лоренцо Монако, Мадонна Смирение со святыми, 1385—1390, Галерея Академии, Флоренция. Ранний пример использования Лоренцо готической стилистики."
              bot.send_photo(chat_id, doc, caption4)
         else:
             bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тогда возвращайся когда захочешь!')

n = input("cmon lets go")
```

Comment: Еще одня проблема, теперь при поптыке отправить фото он пишет что : 020-10-22 19:30:37,557 (util.py:75 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot: "UnicodeDecodeError occurred, args=('charmap',

Answer (score 2):

в конце кода нужно прописать

```
bot.polling()
```

Это нужно для того, чтобы бот не выключился сразу, а работал и проверял, нет ли на сервере нового сообщения

Answer (score -1):

Добавь в конце файла код ниже. Бот будет пытаться получать новые запросы от Telegram. А цикл нужен для того, чтоб при ошибке, бот не останавливался.

```py
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop = True)
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Только не забудь добавить библиотеку `time`.

Comment: Извини, я не могу ответить в комментариях под чужой записью, так как мой рейтинг меньше 50. Так вот тебе выдает ошибку, связанную с кодировкой. Ищется в интернете за одну минуту. Просто в начале файла (самая первая строка) вставь следующее: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.

Comment: Вставил, выдает тоже самое

Comment: Скорее всего Вы пишете на Python 2.7, так как в ней используется кодировка ASCII, а для Python 3.8 - это UTF-8. Есть два варианта, как это можно исправить. Просто перейти на версию Python 3.x, или же во все строки, где вылезала ошибка, нужно добавить `u` перед началом. То есть так: `u'Hello`. Подробнее про это Вы можете прочитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string).

Comment: сижу на python 3.9, ничего не помогает

Comment: Загрузите, пожалуйста, скриншот, на котором будет видна вся информация об ошибке.